# un-ghosting or un-meshing my model

Tags: mesh, faces

I'm trying to switch back to solid view on my model...

At the moment I have this...
[image]

And I want this.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the smooth / flat shading property of an object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17929/where-is-the-smooth-flat-shading-property-of-an-object)

Comment: You have a fox and want to turn it into an elephant? That's gonna take some serious morphing! Just kidding. Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3690/toggle-wireframe-mode-with-hotkey

Comment: ...what does the edit (the added image) mean?

Comment: It means the OP needs to recalculate normals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a little white sphere icon at the bottom of the 3D viewport, right next to the "edit mode" button. there you can switch between different viewport shading modes.
right now you are in the so called wireframe mode. switch it to solid mode to see the faces of your mesh.

[image]

Comment: Thank you... But now I have a SMOOTH object. How can I have flat faces again please? (Uploading photo...)

Comment: Invert normals with ctrl+n and set the shading to flat in the left hand panel.